# I want to generate random number between the 0 to 1. with the interval of 1 second in qt

Tags: c++, qt, delay, wait

I want to generate the random value from 0 to 1 with interval of one second. i have write this code but i cannot understand how can i take delay of 1 second.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QRandomGenerator>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: black;");
    ui->random_label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    ui->random_label->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);");
    
    while(true)
{
    double value = QRandomGenerator::global()->generateDouble();
    qDebug()<<QString::number(value,'f',2);
    //i need delay here of 1 second
}
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

i need deley of 1 second after this line `qDebug()<<QString::number(value,'f',2);` in for loop and i also write the comment where i need delay of 1 second. please help i am new to Qt. how can i take delay of 1 second ?

Comment: To perform things in a Qt program periodically, please, forget about sleep or similar. That would block your event loop. The correct way to do such things is either a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) or a separate thread (which then could use sleep maybe). FYI: [Digital Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-digitalclock-example.html) for how to do things periodically using a `QTimer`.

Comment: This is bad (you should use proposed answer/comment), but here you go: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#sleep

Answer (score 3):

Your `while(true)` will block in the constructor.

Instead, use a `QTimer`, set its interval to one second, and connect its timeout signal to a slot in your `MainWindow` class. In that slot, run the code currently in the body of your `while`.

That moves the "update random number" out of the constructor into the events-handling that is done by the application.

Comment: but my requirement is to generate in infinite loop ad show in window.

Comment: A timer is the correct way. A loop will cause the GUI to freeze because the GUI only updates when your functions exit so that the event loop can process its events. There is a Qt way to force the UI to process but its better to use a timer to accomplish the required behavior anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a timer and attach with random generator using below example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "qtimer.h"
#include "QRandomGenerator"
#include "QDebug"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Initialize timer
    QTimer *_timer = new QTimer(this);

    double value;
    //connect timer to random generator using lambda expression
    connect(_timer,&QTimer::timeout,[&](){
        value = QRandomGenerator::global()->generateDouble();
        qDebug()<<QString::number(value,'f',2);
    });

    //emit timeout after every 1 sec.
    _timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**Note** `generateDouble()` generates one random qreal in the canonical range [0, 1) (that is, inclusive of zero and exclusive of 1).